# Check .dat File whether a file exists using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I check whether a file exists, using Python, Python there are several methods which can be used to check if a file exists, in a certain directory

**My code:**

```
PATH = /abc/python
fname = PATH/UP*.dat

if os.path.isfile(fname)
```

Comment: I can't understand your code, do you mean `PATH = '/abc/python'; fname = PATH + '/UP*.dat'`?

Answer (score 4):

```
os.path.exists(file)   # you cant use wildcard here
os.path.isfile(file)   # to check for is it a file or not
```

You can try this if you want only files:

```
import os
import glob

PATH = "/abc/python/UP*.dat"
filter(os.path.isfile, glob.glob(PATH))
```

Comment: my File name Pattern is UP0*.dat  so more no of file there

Comment: provide full path, if you are in not in same directory, "/abc/python/UP*.dat"

Comment: CHECK MY UPDATED CODE

Comment: python 2.7.10 is support in red hat 5 or not?

Comment: @Ban IF my solution works for you , you can accept my answer, by click on tick sign, thanks